# checkbox checked property is set to true everytime I click on it on edge

Tags: jquery, html

Alright, If you try this fiddle with internet explorer you will see that the console fire `true` everytime you click the checkbox because ie is about to trigger the `click` event after the `change` event.

So if you change `.prop('checked',false)` to true, it will work fine (because of the order events are read)

```js
var checkd = false;

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  checkd = this.checked;
  console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('body').on('click', function() {
  if (checkd) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox'>
```

As you can see, the console show `true` everytime, and ie set the checked property to false imediatly because of the body.click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the order the events are executed. In Edge the `click` on the `body` comes first, even when the checkbox is clicked. In Chrome and other (good) browsers, the `click` and `change` on the checkbox fires first and then propagates up the DOM to the `body`.

To fix this behaviour to work cross-browser you will need to check the body `click` event to see what the clicked element was. If it was *not* the checkbox, then you can uncheck it:

```js
var checkd = false;

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(e) {
  checkd = this.checked;
  console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT' && checkd) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox'>
```

Comment: Nice, I should think about it lol. Dead simple. (for instance, I did it this way `!$('input[type=checkbox]').is(e.target)`  but that is basicaly the same thing) Thank you!